# Using the merge tag in layouts to add external layout resource?

Tags: android

I have a layout I want to reuse, it looks like:

```
<LinearLayout .. >
  <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is in a file called "reuseme.xml". Now I have an activity layout, which like the following, how can I incorporate the layout above into it?:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView />
  <TextView />
  <ReuseMeLayout /> // How do we add this here?
</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that's possible, but I'm not sure how to use the merge tag to accomplish it?

Comment: The `<merge>` tag is for when you want to use multiple top-level tags in your layout. You can use `<include>` to include reference to another layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView />
  <TextView />
  <include
    android:id="@+id/reuseme"
    layout="@layout/reuseme"/>
</LinearLayout>
```